# How can I create a SQLite table using the sqlite3 Python library with parameterized placeholders?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

From Python's documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), I should be able to execute SQL statements using parameterized placeholders. Yet, the code below doesn't work.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("temp.db")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("create table ? (foo text, bar text)", ("table_name",))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    c.execute("create table ? (foo text, bar text)", ("table_name",))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

But if I switch out of using parameterized placeholders, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - no. You can only parameterize values, not object names (in this case, the table's name). If you want to do something like this, you'd have to resort to string manipulation, e.g.:

```
c.execute("create table %s (foo text, bar text)" % ("table_name"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just learning SQL so I never realized the distinction between values and objects.